# TypeError: intents parameter must be Intents, not <class 'discord.flags.Intents'>

Tags: python, android-intent, discord, command, slash

```
from disnake.ext import commands

intents=discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix=".",
    intents=intents,
    test_guilds=[1040948288054112316],
    )

@bot.slash_command(name="test", description="test")
async def test(inter):
    await inter.response.send_message("test")
```

Error: TypeError: intents parameter must be Intents, not <class 'discord.flags.Intents'>.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using disnake? then try this:

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

intents=disnake.Intents.all()
```